# IdentityServer4 Password Grant

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-middleware

I've stood up an instance of identityserver4, an API project, and a UI.

The workflow is as follows:

1. User visits the UI.
2. User provides user name and password to UI.
3. UI sends credentials to back of web app, which uses a password grant to authenticate the user with IdentityServer4.
4. IdentityServer4 returns a token.
5. Token is used to identify who the user is to the UI and that the user has access to certain sections of the site.
6. When the user needs to do something within the site, the token is passed to the API via bearer auth.

The password grant isn't negotiable, as this is a first party app and it makes no sense to redirect the user away from the main site.

What's the proper set of middleware to use for this?  Should I just use a CookieAuthenticationMiddleware and attach the token as a claim?  I'll need to access the claims from HttpContext.User claims.  Do I need to use IdentityMiddleware?

Answer (score 5):

You can request identity scopes using the password grant type and use the userinfo endpoint to resolve them to claims - like in this sample:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Clients/src/ConsoleResourceOwnerFlowUserInfo

And yes - you can use the cookie middleware to persist those claims and the access token for later usage.

Comment: Hello, would I use an implicit flow if the client was a Javascript client where  I can't store secrets? I'm facing a similar scenario where there isn't a need to redirect the User to a separate login screen as the client is a 1st party AngularJS app. Any thoughts would be appreciated!